# AtCoder Beginner Contest 180 Takahashi Unevolved D問題

Tags: python3, c++, アルゴリズム

D - Takahashi Unevolved 解説リンク
https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc180/editorial/219
上記リンク先に掲載されている解答コードで

```
ans+(y-1-x)//b
```

の部分がありますが、ここで-1をする理由がわかりませんでした。
こちらの意味を教えていただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

強さがY**以上**になると進化してしまうため、強さをY-1以下に抑える必要があるからです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
境界値を含めてしまっていましたね...助かりました